# "no such file or directory python" activate environment for Python

Tags: python, environment

When i try activate Environments use cod `$ source project1_env/bin/activate` in Bash they returns the following message *bash: project1_env/bin/activate: No such file or directory*.

Why I can't activate the environment? Environment vile is in the correct folder and inside them all look good.  I use GIT Bash to Python 3.7 on Windows.
[image]

I think the answer can be very simple, but i do not see similar situation/ question on these forum.

Thank you very much for your help!

> this is a conda environment you are trying to activate? – FlyingTeller
>   I think it isn't. Properly the first steps they were the same how in these tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk (to 2:31 here i have i problem)
>
> What does ls -l project1_env/bin return? – hoefling 16 mins ago
>   tymot@DESKTOP-9GQ8RLI MINGW64 ~/Environments
>
> ```
> $ ls -l project1_env/bin
> ls: cannot access 'project1_env/bin': No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: this is a conda environment you are trying to activate?

Comment: What does `ls -l project1_env/bin` return?

Comment: I added above the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First change your direction to your virtualenv directory
2. Then run command .\Scripts\activate which activates the virtual
   environment in windows
3. bin/activate is command that is used to activate virtual environment
   in linux and mac

Comment: "First change your direction to your virtualenv directory" how i can do these? I must open my Git Bash in the same folder where is a file "virtualenv"? or maybe i mast open "virtualenv" and write inside them cod "source project1_env\Scripts\activate"?

Comment: Better to use windows Powershell than using gitbash. Run your gitbash/powershell in the virtualenv folder and type ./Scripts/activate this is activate your virtual environment.

Comment: "source project1_env/Scripts/activate" These work ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem and change the shell to bash and fixed.

Type `echo $0` to get the current environment.

Then type `/bin/bash` to enter the bash environment and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try adding slash before the path:
source /project1_env/bin/activate

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: OK then try source /project1_env/bin/activate.bat

Comment: @pluttik why do you think sourcing a .bat is something that might work?

Comment: still '$  source /project1_env/bin/activate.bat
bash: /project1_env/bin/activate.bat: No such file or directory'

Comment: @FlyingTeller because I think GIT bash needs the extension of files to run

Comment: If you want to run activate.bat then yes you should specify that, but git bash will not understand that file. Instead the file activate (no extension) needs to be sourced

Comment: thanks @FlyingTeller this made me realise that the activate file for bash is not actually present in the Scripts folder, so I copied it there and that worked

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.
copied the file 
Python35\Lib\venv\scripts\posix\activate

into my project1_env\Scripts folder
Then in GIT bash ran:
$ source project1_env/Scripts/activate

NB. change 'Python35' to what your own Python 3.7 folder is called!